# How to loop over json String in c#?

Tags: c#, json

Suppose I have this json saved in my database ?

```
{
    "Type": "IPS",
    "Size": "4.7 Inch",
    "Protection": "OGS with full lamination technology"
}
```

The number of the properties are dynamic. Which means for another row my be 5 or 6 properties. Is there any way to loop over it and retrieve them as objects.

So I want to get the type, size, Protection as fileds to create another json format. How can I do this ?

JObject is a good solution. But let us say I am looping thorough rows to create a dynamic object, only for the json field I want to loop over it and add the properties to the dynamic object that i am creating. Can I achieve this ?

**For Example:**

I ave this

```
var dataTable= DbHelper.GetDatatable(StoredProcedureName);
```

now

```
foreach (DataRow row in rows)
{
    var attributes = row["Attributes"].ToString();
    var obj = new
    {
        Id = (int)row["ID"],
        Name = row["ProductName"].ToString()

    };
    list.Add(obj);
}
```

so row attributes contain the json specified earlier,

Can I loop now to get this final result

```
var obj = new
{
    Id = (int)row["ID"],
    Name = row["ProductName"].ToString(),
    Type = IPS,
    Size = 4.7 Inch,
    Protection = OGS with full lamination technology

};
```

Comment: You can do this if you are using Json.Net  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json)`.

Comment: @HariPrasad Thanks so much it helped.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using Json.NET?  If not, I'd highly recommend it.  If you add it to your project, it becomes as simple as this:

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(str);
```

Here is more information on Json.NET:  http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm

Comment: [And here is direct link to Nuget with it.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

Comment: I modified my question, any help  on it.

Answer (score 2):

You best use an existing JSON library for that. [Newtonsoft JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/) comes to mind.

Example (stolen from their home page)

```
string json = @"{
  'Name': 'Bad Boys',
  'ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00',
  'Genres': [
    'Action',
    'Comedy'
  ]
}";

Movie m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);

string name = m.Name;
// Bad Boys
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a tabelar function that has as parameter this string and inside you split your string in columns and return the result as a table row and make an outer apply with the strings table